# Node,js - Mongoose - Unable to save Geo Polygon - CastError: Cast to number failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geospatial, geo

I am trying to save a Geo Point and a Geo Polygon to Mongo. My tests pass for the Point, but fail for the polygon with:

> CastError: Cast to number failed for value "0,0,3,0,3,3,0,3,0,0" at path "coordinates"

My schema is as follows:

```
var GeoSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
  , coordinates: [Number]
});
GeoSchema.index({ coordinates: '2dsphere' });
```

My test point object which successfully saves:

```
geoPoint = new Geo({
   coordinates: [2,2],
   type: 'Point'
});
```

My test polygon object which fails to save:

```
geoPolygon = new Geo({ 
  type: 'Polygon', 
  coordinates: [[ [0,0], [3,0], [3,3], [0,3], [0,0] ]]
});
```

I have tried changing the type def for "coordinates" to an object and an array, but then both fail to save.

Can anyone advise?

---

*** UPDATE ***

I can now get the tests passing using:

schema:

```
var GeoSchema = new Schema({
  coordinates : { type: [], index: '2dsphere' },
  type: String
});
```

Point object:

```
geoPoint = new Geo({
              geo: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [2,2]
        }
            });
```

Polygon:

```
    geoPolygon = new Geo({ 
geo: {
        type: 'Polygon',
    coordinates: [
        [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0],
           [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0],
           [100.0, 0.0] ]
        ]
    }
    });
```

However when I query the db directly I just see:

```
db.geos.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52b73de00b4dfee427000005"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52b73de00b4dfee427000006"), "__v" : 0 }
```

Can anyone advise why I do not see the saved records?

Comment: how about coordinates: [] ?

Comment: and how do you think about index on a polygon?

Comment: Setting cordinates:[] gives:

MongoError: Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?:{ 0: [ [ 0, 0 ], [
 3, 0 ], [ 3, 3 ], [ 0, 3 ], [ 0, 0 ] ] }

Comment: I am not sure, 2dsphere means that cordinates is [long, lat]

Answer (score 2):

Edit:
It seem that we can set 2dsphere on Point only, not Polygon

so I remove index and it worked.

file: app.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('localhost', 'geo-database');

var GeoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
  , coordinates: []
});

//GeoSchema.index({ coordinates: '2dsphere' });

var Geo = mongoose.model('geos', GeoSchema);

Geo.on('index', function () {
    function cb() {
        console.log(arguments);
    }

    geoPoint = new Geo({
       coordinates: [2,2],
       type: 'Point'
    }).save(cb);

    geoPolygon = new Geo({ 
      type: 'Polygon', 
      coordinates: [[ [0,0], [3,0], [3,3], [0,3], [0,0] ]]
    }).save(cb);
})
```

terminal:

```
$mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 2.5.5-pre-

npm install mongoose
node app
```

output:

```
{ '0': null,
  '1': { __v: 0, _id: 52b6e82493d21060b3000001, coordinates: [ 2, 2 ] },
  '2': 1 }
{ '0': null,
  '1':
   { __v: 0,
     _id: 52b6e82493d21060b3000002,
     coordinates: [ [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] ] },
  '2': 1 }
```

Comment: According to this - http://mongodb.info/2013/05/21/new-blog-new-geo-features-in-mongodb-2-4/ 2dsphere does support polygon. Trying to work out why your test works and mine fails. Will update once I have found the issue. My guess now is my polygon json format.

Comment: That's true. 2dsphere does support Polygon, but mongoose seems to be buggy with this data type.